# When I run request need client CMP for OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, pki, ejbca

When I create request a certificate using the RA mode need to use CMP Client to run command. But I can't see CMP Client for OpeSSL. Where can I find him and how to install?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install CMP for OpenSSL.
It's a fork of the OpenSSL branch that contains CMP extension.

https://github.com/mpeylo/cmposslSL